# infopath publish form into sharepoint server

Tags: infopath

[image]
is it possible to publish an info path 2012 form that have c# code inside it ? i tried to do that but when i click publish and choose one of the publish choices it gives me this message.

> form template can't be published to the following location only site collection administrator can publish sandbox solution to continue contact site collection.

Answer (score 2):

With managed code (.net like c#) you need to deploy your forms using the Administrator-approved for template (advanced) option.  With this option you will push the file out to a file share and then an Administrator will import it into CA and deploy it like a farm solution.